# Normalising Schödinger Wavefunctions using np.linalg.norm

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, physics

I've computed the eigenvalues and eigenstates of a Hamiltonian in Python. I have a matrix containing all the wavefunctions in discrete space `psi`. I'd like to normalise the total wavefunction (or the 'ket') (i.e the matrix of vectors) such that its modulus squared integrates to 1.

I've tried the following:

```
A= np.linalg.norm(abs(psi.T)**2)
normed_psi=psi.T/np.sqrt(A)
    
print(np.linalg.norm(normed_psi))
```

The matrix is transposed so I can access each state using `psi[n]`.
However, the output of the print statement is:

```
20.44795885105457
```

When it should be 1.I feel like I'm not using linalg.norm correctly. I've also tried using my own integral function using the trapezium rule to no success.

I'm not really sure as to what to do at this point. Any help would be great.

Comment: Why `abs(psi.T)**2`? `norm` already implements the Frobenius norm for matrix inputs, so presumably you just want `np.linalg.norm(psi)`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're confusing `np.linalg.norm` and `np.sum`, up to the usual floating point issues these two snippets should be identical:

```
normed_psi = psi.T / np.sqrt(np.sum(psi.T**2))
normed_psi = psi.T / np.linalg.norm(psi.T)
```